# Away3D rotate scene with mouse

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I have a simple scene using the Away3D library and the scene display a simple shape. I'm now dealing with Mouse Events trying to get the effect of rotating the 3D object based on the main coordinates system, but i do not get how to get the initial values when mouse is pressed and what to assign when mouse is moving.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Intermediate Globe example](https://github.com/away3d/away3d-examples-fp11/blob/master/src/Intermediate_Globe.as) in the Away3D repository. There is an HoverController class that should have all the functionality you need to handle mouse inputs and rotate the camera around your 3D shape.